# Create a replica of a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to create a table which is the exact replica but with different table name and without any data from the source table using a sql query!

Answer (score 11):

You can try this

```
SELECT * INTO Table_Copy
FROM Table
where 1=2
```

It will create a empty table with the same structure.

Comment: I don't think you'll get FK's, Indexes, or the like, but if you just need a quick-n-dirty, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

- SQL Server Management Studio
- Object Explorer
- Connect -> Your server
- Databases -> Choose Database
- Tables
- Right Click Your Table
- Script Table as -> Create To -> New Query Editor Window

Answer (score 4):

Jonathan has it (upvoted), and you should probably go with that because it's more portable.  I normally use something similar:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO [New_Table] FROM [Old_Table]
```

I think this better expresses what you're doing, but I like Jonathan's because 'TOP 0' is SQL Server specific, and so his is more portable.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL, you can call SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;

It will display a CREATE TABLE query. Simply change the table name in that query and you're good to go.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: Unfortunately, he tagged `sql-server`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE LIKE table_name
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Unfortunately, he tagged `sql-server`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO Table_Copy
FROM Table
where 1=2
```

This worked very well, when i tried to create a replica of the table without any data's.

```
SELECT * INTO Table_Copy
FROM Table
```

This will create a replica with the data's too.

Answer (score 1):

Can be created by trigger 3 triggers can be created for insert,update and delete operation

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more in your answer as to what those triggers might look like?

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT...
```

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: isnt create table as select an Oracle-ism ?

Comment: you can find it in reference I've posted above. many of RDBS has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into newtablename from sourcetablename
go
truncate newtablename
go
```

That will result in an exact copy but it also copies the data at first which you remove with the truncate statement.

Comment: This works, but has to insert *all* the data in the new table, and then delete it too. That's a lot of useless work which could be avoided with `top 0` or a where-clause that doesn't yield results...

Comment: True! Why didn't I think of a Where 1=2 clause :-)

Answer (score 0):

`create table <new table name> as select * from <old tale name from which you would like to extract data>`

It will create a new table with a different name but will copy all existing data from the old table to new table.

Answer (score 0):

in postgres you can use INHERITS or LIKE keyword to make replica of a table(only copies structure of the table)

**CREATE TABLE client_new (LIKE client);**

or

**CREATE TABLE client_new () INHERITS (client)**

Use of INHERITS creates a persistent relationship between the new child table and its parent table(s). Schema modifications to the parent(s) normally propagate to children as well, and by default the data of the child table is included in scans of the parent(s).
LIKE clause specifies a table from which the new table automatically copies all column names, their data types, and their not-null constraints.Unlike INHERITS, the new table and original table are completely decoupled after creation is complete. Changes to the original table will not be applied to the new table, and it is not possible to include data of the new table in scans of the original table.